# javax.ws.rs.BadRequestException: HTTP 400 Bad Request

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jaxb, jax-rs

I have a JAX RS Rest service whose Request Class is as below

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "CDSRequest")
@XmlSeeAlso({MyClass.class})
@XmlType(name = "CDSRequest", propOrder = {"data", "refClass"})
public class CDSRequest {
    Object data;
    Class  refClass;

    public Class getRefClass() {
        return refClass;
    }

    public void setRefClass(Class refClass) {
        this.refClass = refClass;
    }

    public Object getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Object data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

When I make REST call using the above request object, I get below error. I suspect the issue with generic Object type for data. But i thought `**@XmlSeeAlso**` will resolve it. Please help

```
javax.ws.rs.BadRequestException: HTTP 400 Bad Request
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient.convertToWebApplicationException(AbstractClient.java:426)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientProxyImpl.checkResponse(ClientProxyImpl.java:290)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientProxyImpl.handleResponse(ClientProxyImpl.java:585)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientProxyImpl.doChainedInvocation(ClientProxyImpl.java:551)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientProxyImpl.invoke(ClientProxyImpl.java:205)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy93.pushRawData(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: You provided a POJO, likely the body of what you're expecting to come over.  You didn't provide the resource class.  Likely the true error is found on your server.